KafkaInstanceError: The producer is disconnected when calling the send function more than once
Having error when sending messages when the producer needs to be executed more than once. But when I executed it only once, i got no error. Code provided below to further illustrate my current scenario. Would like to seek help as i'm really stuck right now.
is there something in my implementation/code or is it something on kafkajs library?
using serverless nodejs with kafkajs
On kafka.JS file:
const { Kafka, Partitioners } = require('kafkajs');
const logger = require('../logger');

class KafkaConnection {
  kafkaConfig;
  #kafka;

  constructor(kafkaConfig) {
    if (KafkaConnection.instance) {
      return KafkaConnection.instance;
    }
    this.kafkaConfig = kafkaConfig;
    this.#kafka = new Kafka(kafkaConfig.kafka);
    this.producer = null;

    KafkaConnection.instance = this;
  }

  async connect() {
    if (this.producer) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      this.producer = this.#kafka.producer({
        ...this.kafkaConfig?.producer,
        createPartitioner: Partitioners.DefaultPartitioner,
      });

      await this.producer.connect();
      logger.info('Connected to Kafka');
    } catch (error) {
      logger.error(`Error connecting to kafka:${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
    }
  }

  async disconnect() {
    try {
      await this.producer.disconnect();
      logger.info('Disconnected from Kafka');
    } catch (error) {
      logger.error(`Error disconnecting to kafka:${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = { KafkaConnection };

and here is my producer.js file:
const httpStatus = require('http-status');

const logger = require('../logger');

const { KAFKA_ACKS } = require('../constants/kafka-constants');
const { KafkaInstanceError } = require('../../utils/custom-errors/class-errors');
const { KAFKA_INSTANCE_ERRORS } = require('../constants/error-messages');
const { HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE } = require('../../utils/response-codes');
const { KafkaConnection } = require('./kafka-connection');

class Producer extends KafkaConnection {
  constructor(kafkaConfig = {}) {
    super(kafkaConfig);
  }

  async produceEvent(events = {}) {
    try {
      if (Object.keys(events).length === 0) {
        throw new KafkaInstanceError(
          KAFKA_INSTANCE_ERRORS.EVENT_OBJECT_EMPTY,
          HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE.DATA_PROCESSING_ERROR,
          httpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
        );
      }
      await this.connect();
      logger.info('sending events to kafka notification');

      await this.producer.send({
        topic: this.kafkaConfig.topic,
        acks: this.kafkaConfig?.producerSendOptions?.acks || KAFKA_ACKS.ALL,
        messages: [events],
      });

      logger.info('event sent to kafka notification');

      return events;
    } catch (error) {
      logger.error(error.message);
      throw new KafkaInstanceError(
        error.message,
        error.code || HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        error.statusCode || httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
      );
    }
  }
}

module.exports = {
  Producer,
};

And here is the execution part.
take note: when the event is only consist of 1 record, no error on kafka, but if i make it two, the error occur which is "KafkaInstanceError: The producer is disconnected"
    const kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer(//config here);
    
    const processEvents = async (eventsArg // from SQS) {
       const failedRecords = await Promise.all(
          eventsArg.Records.map(async(event) =>{
          await kafkaProducer.produceEvent(event)
    }
 )

  return {
    batchItemFailures: failedRecords.filter(Boolean),
  };
}

module.exports = {processEvents }


sad, no one can answer it
